# Message passing using akka with case

Tags: scala, akka, actor, message

```
class ActorA(processB:ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  def receive = {
    case (0) => 
       println(1000)
    case (_) => 
       println (2*_)
   }
}
```

I am writing this code to output 1000 if message passed is 0 and 2x otherwise but it is telling me that * is not a member of Any and missing parameter type for expanded function

---

Answer (score 2):

The messages to actors can be of any type so your final pattern is against a value of type Any.
If you want to only handle Int you need to specify the type in the pattern.
Additionally you can't match against _ and then use _ as if it's a variable.  They mean different things.  The first one in the case means that you don't care what the value is.
The second one is a placeholder for a function parameter.

What you want is:

```
class ActorA(processB:ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging{
   def receive = {
      case (0) => 
         println(1000)
      case x:Int => 
         println (2*x)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this case to the receive function:

```
case (number:Int) => println (2*number)
```

Remember, that when you use the underscore _ in the case, you cannot use the variables value after the => sign.